# Increased font-size of text for the Uploadify Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I want to increase the text for the uplodify button without chaning the button size.

```
E.g:  'buttonText'  : 'Upload Image'.
```

I want to increase the size of upload image text only.

Comment: please suggest me how to do that...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) How about the markup of your button?

Comment: i have done the image uplode using ajax but i want to change the font size only of that uplodify button. Currently i'm not able to change the text font size that's it...
please provide me suggestions, how to do???

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery to change the text:

```
$('#button_id').text("Upload Image"); // change text of button
```

Then with CSS you can keep the width the same:

```
#button_id {
width: 50px; /* change this to what you want */
}
```

Remember to change `button_id` to the actual id of your button.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NathanJohnson/67cv3/

Comment: @amol I would appreciate if you accepted my answer, it rewards me for helping you and it gives you one or two points, plus it tells others that the question is answered. Learn more about accepting answers on Stack Overflow here: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/166675)